# Multiline textbox in html instead textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

in a project of mine, 
when trying to send contents of text-area using commons file upload, i got null value,

```
<td>Message</td>
        <td><textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="38" style="resize: none;"  ></textarea>
        </td>
```

later i used hidden field and succeed in getting the value

```
        <td>Message</td>
        <td><textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="38" style="resize: none;"  ></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" id="msgid" name="msgid"/>
        </td>
```

But i want to use multiple line textbox instead of text-area,
can any one tell me how to use multiple line in textbox?

Comment: How are you trying to get what is in the textarea? Please post your javascript.

Comment: as i mentioned i used apache commons file upload for file upload. if any other field like text-field are present in html page these values are available in servlet but not the text-area values e.g. .... if (item.isFormField()) {
      // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                  String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                  String fieldvalue = item.getString();